# Wipe all stored prometheus metrics?

Tags: prometheus

I have install prometheus (v2.1.0 from Ubuntu 18.04's apt repository), and I have played around with adding hosts & metrics and all that for about a week. I want to “start fresh” and delete all existing stored data & metrics. How can I do this?

Comment: well i do testing on a vm or container,wipe it and use the snapshot to start over,forgotten about to do it? Mostly i would suggest to look for howtos that regards to backup this peace because then you know how to get rid off tze data. Thats how i do on generic unknown software

Answer (score 3):

Prometheus stores its TSDB in `/var/lib/prometheus` in most default packages.

It will initialize it on startup if it doesn't exist so simply clearing its content is enough.

If you've played around with `remote_write` however, you'll need to clear the long-term storage solution which will vary depending on which storage solution it is.

If you want to reset its configuration, delete `/etc/prometheus` and reinstall the package.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Prometheus v2.47.0 on macOS.

After installing I see a `data` subdirectory.

I deleted that directory and it seems to have removed all the data/metrics.